# LM386 not passing white noise signal that was generated by a second LM386 (updated)

Tags: noise, lm386

I am using an LM386 to generate white noise. The circuit also has a second 386 for an on-board audio amplifier. Both chips are powered by the same 9V battery.

The audio amp won't pass the white noise signal and I can't figure out why, is there an impedance-matching issue? I have tried different value capacitors to buffer between the two ICs, resistors, resistors-to-ground, and an op-amp with 1:1 ratio.

When I turn the noise generator on and off, I can hear like a DC 'pop' on the speaker, but I can't hear the noise. When I tap the signal at C3 (between the two 386's) and plug that into a commercial amp, I can hear the signal fine. There's just something about that second amp that won't pass the white noise.

[image: schematic]
https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/g85pxv/white-noise-and-lm386-amp/

Comment: How are you mixing the signals together - do you have a circuit to show us?

Comment: The output of each signal generator first goes through a 1:1 op-amp (I'm using a LM324). This buffers the signal generators from each other. Then the outputs of these op-amps go through blocking capacitors to an end point. From this point, connecting to the commercial guitar amp sounds great, but connecting to my on-board LM386 amp, only the white noise signal is blocked.

Comment: "end-point" - what does that mean? Is it some resistors that allow the signals to mix with each other?

Comment: no, the ends of the capacitors are tied together, and that's my signal, goes into the amp from there. Somewhat baffling though as I troubleshoot - I have removed all the other components and just plugged the noise generator directly into the amp (with and without capacitors, with and without resistors in series and to ground) and all the same result - the audio amp just doesn't want to pass that white noise!

Comment: @pinhead, a schematic of **your actual circuit** would be very helpful. It would be much easier to read a complete schematic than to try to work out what is in it from your comments and text.

Comment: After the caps, and for each signal, try joining them via individual 1k ohms resistors. This will be a small but adequate mixer. I have a suspicion that the outputs on the 386 don't like being joined to each other via caps. Also if you want to proceed with any help i do suggest you get the full circuit posted.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I added a schematic of my circuit, with the mixer eliminated and the other sound sources hidden. I have tried this configuration while trouble shooting, and it won't pass the white noise. I've tried all sorts of things on the connection between the two 386's - a capacitor, a resistor, an op-amp, a resistor to ground..... THANKS!

Comment: where is the blocking cap between the two LM386?

Comment: I didn't draw it in, but I've tried with and without capacitors, and of varying size.

Comment: Listen dude, you've been repeatedly asked to show the full circuit and you still haven't. This is getting very frustrating and until we see what your circuit is I really don't think anyone is going to be able to answer this. FULL circuit please

Comment: thanks Andy, I'll have to post the full thing tomorrow, its big. But the schematic I included above is the whole point of the question. I've reduced the entire project to this relationship between the two 386s and thats why I'm wondering - is there an impedance matching issue between the two amps?

Comment: @pinhead we dont need to see the entire rest of what you are doing, but things like, "Where is X capacitor" where you state you just have not drawn it in is an issue. Please include every components in the circuit yo have here. Circuitlab might make drawing it a bit easier.

Comment: Why are you feeding an LM386 with another?

Comment: @MattYoung There are other sound sources being mixed at the input of the audio amp (square waves generated with a 40106 Schmitt Trigger Oscillator). The other sound sources pass through the amp fine to the speaker. With those components removed (until the circuit is as drawn above), I still have the problem.

Comment: @pinhead I get that there are other sources, but the LM386 does not function well as an op amp. You would be better off to use a CMOS op amp to get sum your signals, and feed that to a single LM386 for amplification.

Comment: @MattYoung Sounds like you have the start of an answer!

Comment: I don't see any negative feedback on the second amp, and it's hard to work out which input it's connected to. Proper circuit diagram with triangular opamps!

Answer (score 1):

Pin 3 (final stage) might need a resistor to ground - try 1kohm. All the application circuits I've seen do have a lowish value.

Also I have reservations about it working correctly without a low impedance on the 1st stage speaker output (after the capacitor) so try a resistor on pin 3 (2nd stage) that is more like 10 ohms.